# parse body of react tag

Tags: parsing, reactjs, tags

Assuming we have  :

```
class Email extends React.Component{

   constructor(props){
      super(props);
   }
   validate(){
       return true;
   }
   render(){
        <input placeholder={this.is.what.i.ask.for.to.be.parsed.from.its.body} onFocus={this.validate} />  
   }
 }
```

Now When , I resue it, i want to call :

```
 <Email >
   someone@company.com
</Email>
```

How to parse `someone@company.com` from the body of `Email` tag.

---

I Knew that it can be done by calling `<Email holder="someone@company.com" />` & i must update `render` by `this.props.holder`.

Therefore,  we access to React Attributes  by `this.props`, HOWEVER, Is there something to access its body with the Built-in way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you should use `this.props.children`:

```
render() {
    return (<input placeholder={this.props.children} onFocus={this.validate} />);
}
```

As an aside, remember that you need to bind `this` for your `onFocus` callback! A popular way to do this is from within the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank u .. for the last note , i already inject `this` using : 
`[].forEach((method)=>{
            this[method]=this[method].bind(this);
        })` ...& sure you will understand why i did that  ... :))

Answer (score 2):

`this.props.children` gives you access to a Component's children.  In this case the email address content would be considered a child of `Email` Component.

It would probably be best to use the [React.Children.only](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.only) utility to make sure that there is only a single child.

Something like this should work:

```
class Email extends React.Component{

   constructor(props){
      super(props);
   }
   validate(){
      return true;
   }
   render(){
      return <input placeholder={React.Children.only(this.props.children)} onFocus={this.validate} />;  
   }
 }
```

Comment: Nice, `React.Children.only` looks useful.